# How can I export a scatter_matrix figure, produced with Pandas and Cufflinks, as a local html file?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, plotly-python

Cufflinks can create very nice scatter_matrix figures directly from a pandas dataframe. The example code works well and prints the interactive figure inside Jupyter. I want to save this to a local html file.

I tired passing the filename argument, but it doesn't help.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.scatter_matrix(filename='scatter-matrix.html')
```

I want the produced image to be exported to a local html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around it, although I believe there must be a better way. I store the generated scatter_matrix as a dictionary (asFigure=True) and use the plotly.offline function `plot` to save the dictionary as a local html file.
To avoid the file to be opened, use auto_open=False.

```py
from plotly.offline import plot
import cufflinks as cf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
a = df.scatter_matrix(asFigure=True)
plot(a, filename='scatter-matrix.html', auto_open=False)
```

Comment: With Plotly 3.x this is the recommended way. With Plotly 4.x you can do `fig.write_html()`

Comment: Cufflinks seems to not be working yet with Plotly 4.x
https://github.com/santosjorge/cufflinks/issues/196